# google script not sharing

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

I'm creating a spreadsheet for the bar I manage so everyone can sign up for their shifts. I want to prevent anyone changing people's shifts once they've been inputted, and found a script online that does that. It works fine and as intended on my device, but when testing it on other devices the script doesn't seem to run, and I'm able to input other names/delete names from already filled in cells. This is the first time I'm using google script so I'm not sure if its a simple mistake I'm making so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Test spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OpEuuI7FZwWoTLkauh0DpAbz4c7P1jCY3QCee6aTRbI/edit?usp=sharing

Cheers!

Comment: Why not just protect ranges and give specific permissions ranges to specific people?

Comment: Please add more details about the devices that you are using. Are all of them mobile devices? Which OS have they ? Are you testing it using your account of differents accounts? Are using a web browser or mobile apps? It's worth to say that questions about code that isn't working should include a [mcve] in the question rather than link an external file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies! So the only way people can edit the sheet is with a shareable link, and I've protected everything other than what they need to edit (so they can only select their name from the data validation on the Bar, Waiting, and KP columns on the 'Rota' tab). Rubén I tested the shareable link on one of my colleagues accounts and that's the problem I'm having where the script doesn't seem to work as intended. I have over 60 staff so I'm sure there's various OSs and ways people will be accessing the sheet which is why I'm wanting lots of flexibility with it